# IIS output cache - how to add a resource to cache, whatever the path

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, iis

I have a **multi-tenant** .Net **MVC4** application running on **IIS 7.5**

I'd like IIS to cache in its output cache, a common resource that should be accessible under every tenant, every controller.

For example:

> /MyTenant1/MyController/MyAction1/Help
>   /MyTenant1/MyController/MyAction2/Help
>   /MyTenant2/MyController/MyAction1/Help
>   [...]

All those Help are exactly the same.
I'd like IIS to cache Help.aspx as a single resource, and serve it for any tenant, any controller, any action...

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Are this tenants under the same IIS WebSite/Application or each tenant has it's own WebSite/Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the previous answer will get the desired result (sorry can't comment due to low score). OP can disagree with me here but just my thought...

The cache key is composed of full path which in the OP's case will contain:

/MyTenant1/MyController/MyAction1/Help
/MyTenant2/MyController/MyAction1/Help

and hence will be unique thereby ending up in multiple copies of the same content.

You can write a custom cache provider and come up with a key translation logic to map these distinct keys to common key (by ignoring tenancy bit?) See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.caching.outputcacheprovider%28VS.100%29) for this. That's one solution.

Other, not so elegant, solution (IMHO) may be to make a single page (no tenancy) and use server rewrite rules to map to it from other tenancies.

Comment: Yes ! I think you're right @i.net - Let me check and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Indeed, it works fine with a custom OuputCacheProvider. Here is an implementation that inspired my to finally have my common "/Help" page be cached whatever the tenant path was: [Output Cache Provider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94803/ASP-NET-Output-Cache-Provider). And here is an article by Scott Gu [Extensible Output Caching](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/27/extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use OutputCache attribute, for every Action

```
[OutputCache(Duration=600)]
public ActionResult MyAction1
```

Or you can set a CacheProfile

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Cache1Hour")]
public ActionResult MyAction1 ...
```

and define it a WebConfig

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
          <outputCacheProfiles>
              <add name="Cache1Hour" duration="3600"/>
          </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
</system.web>
```

Furthermore, you can define where the cache will be located:

> You can set the Location property to any one of the following values:
>
> · Any
>
> · Client
>
> · Downstream
>
> · Server
>
> · None
>
> · ServerAndClient

Tutorial with examples:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: Thank you for these hints. However, in my case, these solutions let IIS keed as many cache versions of "/Help" as controllers, actions and tenants. By default, IIS vary the cache by the path of the request.
Thus, how could I tell IIS to keep the same version of "/Help", for two different pathes ?
/MyTenant1/MyController/MyAction1/Help
/MyTenant2/MyController/MyAction1/Help

Comment: @JaffarMoore ok! Now we have the solution provide by i.net :)